# Kohana 3.2 название контроллеров

Tags: kohana

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста как подключить контроллер additional_fields.php или additionalFields.php? просто если писать все без каких либо разделителей будет не красиво и возможно даже не понятно...Пробовал AdditionalFields но подключение не удалось.

Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Назовите его `Controller_AdditionalFields` положите в `controller/additionalfields.php` и всё будет работать, т.к. в `Kohana 3.2` автозагрузчик делает [так](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.2/develop/classes/kohana/core.php#L499).

Если пройти по ссылке, то станет понятно, что если назовете класс `Controller_Additional_Fields`, то надо будет положить его в `controller/additional/fields.php`

Для `Kohana 3.3` название файла будет `AdditionalFields.php` потому что в ней кое-что [изменили](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/Core.php#L506).

Comment: Controller_Additional_Fields -- Да вот насчет этого я уже понял)) просто уже год с коханой и не раз возникала потребность применить разделитель но руки не доходили спросить как это правильно сделать, а то не красиво писать все слитно(Additionalfields) не сразу понятно)